# Extending Spring Batch Meta data table schema

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

Is it possible to extend Spring Batch meta data table schema. For some operational and other reasons, the desire is to have one set of meta data tables used by multiple applications. I know that there is support for Table name prefix which can be used to have one set of metadata tables for each Batch Application (use case), but lets assume for now, I am not allowed to do that :).
To have App based jobs, can I add a new table, lets say BATCH_APPLICATION. Then I would change BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE table to have a FK of APP_ID pointing to BATCH_APPLICATION. This way every Job is in context of an application and hence we can have multiple applications using same set of meta data tables. Here is a potential change as ER diagram
[image]

Now my questions are

1. How to change the corresponding Job and JobInstance JAVA classes and all associated CRUD to reflect above changes. I am assuming I need new classes extending Job and JobInstance, say AppJob and AppJobInstance. Also extend JobInstanceDao, say AppJobInstanceDao . Then to hook it to JPA repository etc., I need to extend JobRepositoryFactoryBean, mainly createJobInstanceDao() to return my new AppJobInstanceDao that uses my new class say AppJobInstance. I need to work out all fine details, but I wanted to understand if I am thinking in right direction or if I am going totally off tangent.
2. What are key things to look for, in addition to all Java JobRepository related changes?
3. Is this really a practical solution or is it totally wrong approach?

It will be good to hear from experts of Spring Batch projects, as such inputs will help us to come to a more pragmatic decision internally for whether to pursue this route or whether to drill more into why operations thinks using table name prefix is not an option and what can be done about it.

Comment: You could but that would mean you would need to rewrite parts of the Spring Batch infrastructure. You would basically need to change the storage, the launching, etc. So practical it is probably not. But do you really need that application stuff, the application (assuming the app is the job) should only contain a single job, if the job name is unique already (you can make up a naming scheme) you are already good to go without all that additional effort for little gain.

Answer (score 0):

You already can use the same spring batch database tables from multiple applications so long as the job names are unique.  Each application would contain it's own list of @Job beans that you create and that the application can manage (launch, stop, restart etc) while sharing the same spring batch database tables as other applications.

Spring batch provides a JobRegistry (https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/JobRegistry.html) that can be used to see which jobs exist in each application.  It can be populated with your @Job beans on startup

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBatchConfiguration {

     
    @Autowired
    private JobRegistry jobRegistry;

    // populate the jobRegistry with all @Job beans at startup   
    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor() {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor postProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        postProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return postProcessor;
    }

    
}
```